# BATproject error when querying monetdb database

Tags: sql, database, monetdb

I'm running into issues when running the following query on a monetdb database:

```
SELECT
    tpuc.tbl1_col1,
    s.tbl2_col1,
    COUNT(s.tbl2_col2)
FROM
    tbl2 AS s INNER JOIN
    tbl AS tpuc ON (s.tbl2_col2=tpuc.tbl1_col2)
GROUP BY
    tpuc.tbl1_col1,
    s.tbl2_col1
```

> Can not create object BATproject: does not match always

tbl2 has just a little over 35mil rows and tbl1 has around 300k rows. The query runs flawlessly on a database with an identical structure but considerably less data (about a tenth) so I assume this is related to the amount of data. Does anyone have experience with this error?

I've ran queries on larger databases than this and monetdb seems to be designed to handle more data so I'm thinking that this is maybe some sort of error on my part / data corruption. However, the error doesn't seem to be documented anywhere so every little bit of insight is appreciated.

later edit:
running into the same error when running simpler queries such as select group by

Thanks

Comment: do you have any indexes set?  what version of monetdb are you using?  is it possible to give a reproducible example?  thanks!

Comment: no indexes, was running monetdb 11.17.9 on saucy salamander. a distribution downgrade to 12.04 lte did not help but it seems to function properly (for now) using an older version of monetdb (11.15.17). running the latest version did not cause any issues on a regular drive (some vanilla 7200rpm disk) on the test machine but seems to implode after 3-400k inserted values on an ssd raid. I'm currently inserting data from a queue at around 2-300 inserts / second which is probably somehow tied to the issue.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm facing the same error message, although I don't know if it's the same problem. https://www.monetdb.org/pipermail/users-list/2014-June/007359.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not happen, please report this as a bug at http://bugs.monetdb.org/ . Please also include the schema (CREATE TABLE ...) and some example data. Also, you can try if the Jan2014-SP1 release candidate solves the issue. Download the release candidate at http://dev.monetdb.org/downloads/testing/

Comment: thanks, it's already reported. I'll give the rc a try when we deploy our next build

Comment: problem persists even with the rc